# Do Python's `lambda` remember references to outer variable rather value?

Tags: python, lambda, partial-application

I was expecting Python's `lambda` to keep reference to value of local variables. So when I wrote:

```py
>>> ls = [
...     lambda: x*x
...     for x in range(3)
... ]
>>> [f() for f in ls]
[4, 4, 4]
```

I expected the result to be: `[0,1,4]` where each lambda would remember a different value of `x` used to create it. But as you can see above, the result is `[4,4,4]` as if they all have been eval against the last value of `x`. This is unintuitive as `x` does not even exists in the context the `lambda`s are evaluated in.

```py
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Just to make sure, I create a local scope to change value of `x` after the last `lambda` creation to see if the evaluation use the last value of `x` and it sure did.

```py
>>> def get_ms():
...     ms = []
...     for x in range(3):
...         ms.append(lambda: x*x)
...     print([f() for f in ms])
...     x = 3
...     return ms
...
>>> ms = get_ms()
[4, 4, 4]
>>> [f() for f in ms]
[9, 9, 9]
```

NOTE: It appears inner function also works the same way.

**First question**: Is my above analysis of the situation correct? (Lambda remember references to local variable used to create it rather than value of the variable, and this variable somehow persist outside its scope)

**Second question**: What is behaviour supposed to be used for? Or is just an undefined part of specification?

The easiest way I can think of to get the behaviour I originally wanted is:

```
>>> import functools
>>> def square(x):
...     return x*x
...
>>> ls_ = [
...     functools.partial(square, x)
...     for x in range(3)
... ]
>>> [f() for f in ls_]
[0, 1, 4]
```

**Final question**: Is there a better way than using `functools.partial` as seen above?

Comment: It works the same as with other functions: it looks up the value of the variable named `x` *when called*. The function body isn’t evaluated until call time.

Comment: BTW, the usual way of getting your desired behaviour is `[lambda x=x: x*x for x in range(3)]`

Comment: The way *I* prefer is to make an explicit function factory, `def  square_maker(x): return lambda x: x` and then in your loop, `ls = [square_maker(x) for x in range(3)]`

Comment: @ForceBru That is nice, thank you.

Comment: And thanks to the one who mark this question as duplicate. I'll leave the question up for extra search coverage unless there is a suggestion to just delete it.